# app.use(validator()); ^ TypeError: validator is not a function

Tags: node.js, validation, express, webstorm

I am working on a project for my summer training and I was asked to create a login page using `Node.js` however, after installing `express-validator` and entered the codes I suppose to in the `app.js` file it prints out an error each time I run the `app.js` or the `www` in the bin file telling me "`validator` is not a function".

And most importantly, I am using WebStorm as my IDE on Windows.

This is the error it prints out;

```
app.use(validator());
        ^
TypeError: validator is not a function
```

Here is the code from the `app.js` file;

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var validator = require('validator');
var session = require('session');


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(validator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({secret:'max', saveUninitialize: false, resave: false}));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Right, so... `validator` isn't a function.

Answer (score 6):

Uninstall the current version: `npm uninstall express-validator`.

And install the older version: `npm install express-validator@5.3.1`.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, you're using the wrong module.  The [validator module](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/blob/master/validator.js#L1095) exports an object with a bunch of validation methods on it.  So, your `validator` is just an object, not something that can be used as Express middleware.

Perhaps, you want to use the [Express validator module](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/blob/master/validator.js#L1095) which is designed to work as middleware?

Comment: So do I replace this Express validator module into the validator.js or what?

Comment: @BlackWolf - Read the doc for the module I showed you.  Following the instructions there.  No point in me repeating that doc.

Answer (score 0):

I had your problem too ، Replacing ^ 5.1.2 will replace version 6  the problem resolve.
The problem is how the package is configured

at package json 
"express-validator": "^5.1.2",

npm i

Comment: He uses `validator` instead of `express-validator`