# TypeError: validator is not a function - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to use express validator for my sign up form.

I have installed it with:

```
npm install express-validator --save
```

Then I added it to my server.js file:

```
var validator = require('express-validator');
var app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cvit', {useNewUrlParser: true});

require('./config/passport');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(cookieParser());


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(validator()); 

app.use(session({
    secret: 'This is my test key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection})
}));

app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

when I run my application I am getting following error:

```
app.use(validator()); 
        ^

TypeError: validator is not a function
```

I am not sure why because I did install it but it seems like it's not being recognized.

Any tip is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am using this validate function

```
function validate(req, res, next){
    req.checkBody('firstname', 'Firstname is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('lastname', 'Lastname is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is Invalid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password Must Not Be Less Than 5').isLength({min:5});
    req.check("password", "Password Must Contain at least 1 Number.").matches(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[0-9a-z]{5,}$/, "i");

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        var messages = [];
        errors.forEach((error) => {
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });

        req.flash('error', messages);
        res.redirect('/signup');
    }else{
        return next();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [app.use(validator()); ^ TypeError: validator is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794413/app-usevalidator-typeerror-validator-is-not-a-function)

Comment: which version of `express-validator` are you using?

Comment: @pzaenger that answer didn't solve my question!

Comment: @1565986223 "express-validator": "^6.1.1"

Comment: After your update: Are you sure `var validator = require('express-validator');` imports your function `validate` and not something from the package `express-validator`?

Comment: @pzaenger it doesn't import my function validate it imports `validator()` `app.use(validator()); ` and error says `validator is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your `express-validator` version, it might not (or might) be a function. [`v6.0.0`](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/releases/tag/v6.0.0) onwards exports a function and the old APIs are deprecated.

Their documentation page seems to lack behind.

The old version `exports` *an object not a middleware* which you can use as described in [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/index.html)

```
const { check } = require('express-validator');

app.post('/user', [
  check('username').isEmail(), // <-- check as middleware
  (req, res) ...
```

Comment: I have added edit to show you my validate function can you please check it? How could I use your tip in my code. Thanks!